# xcode workspace with 2 projects. how to create object from project 1 in project 2?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've created workspace and drag 2 projects.

Now, I want to create object (view controller) from project1, in project 2.

After I  add "#import "headerFileFromProject1.h" , xcode error is the header not found.
and I guess there is place where I need to set some path (although its strange cause the workspace knows the path of the 2 projects and by that, their headers files also)

I read a lot about sub projects, workspace, static library, but I did not understand if what I'm trying to to do is 5-6 steps  or something with alot of settings.

If its 5-6 steps, please help me complete the puzzle. If it's more than that, I give up and I will wait for xcode version 11.

Again, all I want to do is take 2 xcode projects and create object from the first project inside the second project. maybe I'm asking to much :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different Xcode projects may share common code (identical source files): Create a corresponding Group in the Navigation area of each project and add shared files. Purposefully, the folder for shared source should neither be a subfolder of the projects sharing the code.
Possibly, you need to properly setup header search paths.

Depending on your needs, a better approach might be to create a library project and share that library through linking the client binary to the library. The best step by step guide how to create and use a library is in the official documentation itself.

Comment: project1 is big project. with alot of files, sub libraries(of files), build settings and more.

project 2 can be empty project (for the purpose of this testing)
I want to create view controller from project 1 , in project 2.

what is the best way to do that ? static library ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the same files: `headerFileFromProject1` .h and .m to your project 2, without copying it. Then, when you edit it, it will change in both projects.